# Таймер на С++

Tags: winforms, c++

Привет всем!

Я много думал, искал, писал, но никак не получалось создать таймер в label1 по нажатию кнопки. Для Windows Form.

Кто знает, напишите, буду рад!

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой алгоритм

Пишем функцию, в которой

1. Запускаем цикл со счетчиком.
2. Переводим значение счетчика в часы-минуты-секунды (типа, count==100 -> h == 0, min ==1, sec == 40).
3. Устанавливаем соответственное значение поля Text у Label.
4. Засыпаем на 1 сек.
5. Возвращаемся в п. 2.

И самое главное - все это запускаем в отдельном потоке. Для прерывания создаем некую булевую переменную, которую цикл счетчика может на определенном этапе проверять, и если она == true, то цикл продолжается, если false, то прерывается.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

```
public ref class ClassWithTimer
{
   static Timer^ timer = gcnew Timer;

   static void ProcessTimerEvent(Object^ , EventArgs^)
   {
   }

   void StartTime()
   {

      timer->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(ProcessTimerEvent);

      timer->Interval = 5000;
      timer->Start();

   }
};
```

Нужно запускать таймер по нажатию кнопки, а в обработчике обновляет содержимое индикатора.